# ASP.NET MVC 4 FormCollection is Empty using Angularjs $Http.post

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

I’m submitting a form post using **Angularjs (1.2.20)** to **Microsoft ASP.Net MVC 4**:

```
public ActionResult Save2(FormCollection customer)
{
   //TODO: Do some stuffs...
   return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

However, the `FormCollection` is empty. I know that the data is being sent because if I change it to the following code below (using strongly type `CustomerVm`), it works as expected.

```
public ActionResult Save1(CustomerVm customer)
{
   //TODO: Do some stuffs...
   return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

I’m using `FormCollection` so that I can add **ASP.Net** anti-forgery token in the data (instead of headers). Below is my custom javascript code. Also you can find the entire code (**Visual Studio**) [here](https://github.com/mtekasetya/AngularjsMvcPost)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send the request with a content-type of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and encode the request body as such. This is a good start but it's sending the data as JSON.

```
var data = JSON.stringify(customer);

// FormCollection
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/Home/Save2',
    //dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset-UTF-8',
    //contentType: 'application/json; charset-UTF-8',
    data: data
});
```

Turning the object into a URL encoded form is actually pretty complex. Thankfully, Ben Nadel has already created a [transformRequestAsFormPost service to do this](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2615-posting-form-data-with-http-in-angularjs.htm) via a request transformer. You can give it a try by adding in his code and making this change to yours...

```
myApp.factory('customerSvc', function ($http, transformRequestAsFormPost) {
    return {
        // ...
        save2: function (customer, antiForgeryToken) {
            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: '/Home/Save2',
                transformRequest: transformRequestAsFormPost,
                data: data
            });
        }
    };
});
```